# React: Why <Input> puts the event object at the end of the argument of the event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The title may sound vague, so here is a snippet of code to explain what it means...

```
changeInput = (index, event) => {
 //How come "event" is the second argument?
 //I didn't put "event" (but index) in the code below.
 //Why isn't the argument (event, index)?
}

render() {
    const index = 0;
    return (
        <input type="text" 
               onChange={this.changeInput.bind(this,index)} />
      );
    }
}
```

In React.js, form elements (`input`, `textarea` etc) send the event object to the event handler (`changeInput`).

However, I'm a little confused with the order. **Why `event` is put at the end of the event handler, instead of at the beginning?**

It might be nicer to use an anonymous function for `onChange`.

(i.e. `(event) => this.changeInput.bind(event,index)` may be better looking)

Before doing so, I'd like to know the reason, but can't find any clue in [the official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `index` here `.bind(this, index)`. Bind passes first arg as a context and all other args will be passed to the function on call

Here is an implementation of bind for better understanding:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function bind(context, ...bindArgs) {
  return (...args) => {
    return this.call(context, ...bindArgs, ...args);
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. `Bind passes first arg as a context and all other args will be passed to the function on call`. 

I'm still not 100% sure about this. Why does `index` come before `event`? Both `index` and `event` are `all other args` in your definition, am I correct? Why does `bind()` put `event` as the second argument?

Comment: @Hiroki added a code which is showing the common implementation of bind. Bind args goes first because it's according to w3c standards.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation for bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The first arg you send to bind is `thisArg` (which is used to determine `this` inside the function, `changeInput` in your case), the rest arguments is passed to the function.

```
this.changeInput.bind(this, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Will result in

```
this.changeInput(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

The reason you've to call `.bind` is a story itself. You can search for "javascript this context" to learn more about `this` and how it works, it's worth learning that :)